# How can I express logical AND unambiguously but simply?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In colloquial English AND is often misused, or at least misunderstood, as meaning OR, and vice versa.

Thus, when writing a webpage instructing people to enter locations and distances from those locations to determine a search area by the INTERSECTION of those circles rather than their union, how might I express the instruction both clearly and simply?

I've currently got:

[image]

Comment: That _is_ how you do it. Also, this strikes me as something that http://ux.stackexchange.com/ would be able to answer.

Comment: You could also put 'both' after 'are', omitting 'also', for two constraints.

Comment: One work-around that I have seen to avoid this issue is to provide a separate form element allowing the users to choose between "search for all conditions" and "search for any condition".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a well-studied problem in user interface design, and can be better answered elsewhere.

Comment: @jimm101: please provide a link?

Comment: Find places that meet all of the following constraints:

Comment: I would **really** like to see examples of how AND used in this way might be misunderstood. How on earth can it mean OR?

Comment: @AndrewLeach:  FumbleFingers explains it in their answer, quoted below.  I'm glad to see this question reopened because I was very interested in just how the ambiguity arises, as much as the UX aspects.

Comment: @IanWorthington Please **add examples into your question.** I dispute the entire premise that *and* can mean anything but *and.*

Comment: @AndrewLeach:  "Show me places within 100 miles of London and Birmingham" might mean either either the union of those groups or their intersection.

Comment: @IanWorthington Would you please **put it in your question** and explain how your dialog does not disambiguate it.

Answer (score 2):

The "also" in your form is redundant.  "AND" is sufficient. It is not accepted usage to interpret it as anything but a *combination* of the two, which does not allow for only one of them to satisfy the conditions.

Comment: I agree totally that AND _should_ be sufficient/"also" is redundant. Regrettably though, in colloquial usage, it seems that is not.  Hence my search for a plain and simple version instruction unambiguously interpretable.

Comment: We have an expression in AmE that you may be familiar with: "_You can't fix stupid._"  If the form conforms with normal usage as it is taught, then you may find that varying from that a) causes confusion, b) discredits the form (and possibly the whole site) by making the form creator appear to have poor mastery of the language, c) doesn't solve the problem because visual cues are misleading.  One alternative solution might be to place the fields _adjacent_ to each other, rather than in separate visual zones vertically. This implies they have equal importance; upper-lower implies superiority.

Answer (score 2):

From @FumbleFingers:

"It seems to me the obvious way to disambiguate is simply to reinstate one "deleted" word from

> Find places that are [condition #1] and *are* also [condition #2].

This explicitly forces *also* to apply to both instances of *are*, ruling out the possibility of it applying to *and also find* (which alternative gives rise to the *or* interpretation)."

Answer (score 0):

Although 'and' alone expresses the intended conjunctive meaning, it is as you mention liable to misinterpretation. To head that misinterpretation off at the pass, so to speak, you can use "the modern colourless" 'while'. This use of while has the additional advantage (if you like) of applying to mobile 'places'. For example, 'while' applies both conditions to airplanes, helicopters, automobiles, RVs (caravans), mobile homes or offices, but only while such 'places' are within 200 miles of both Birmingham and London.

> **while**, ... *conj.* ...
>   ....
>   **c.** In modern colourless use: At the same time that, besides that, in addition to the fact that; often = and at the same time, and besides.
>
> ["while, adv. (and adj.) and conj. (and prep.)". OED Online. September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/228336?rskey=wQr12H&result=3&isAdvanced=false (accessed October 07, 2016).]

As indicated by extrapolation from that definition, 'and at the same time' or, more likely, 'and besides' would also suit your purposes. I find such constructions less graceful than the simple 'while also', but 'and besides' might better suit *your* sense of the colloquial.